# Construct a Bregman divergence from Wasserstein distance

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, it.information-theory, optimal-transportation, wasserstein-distance

I was wondering whether one has studied the Bregman divergence arising from a squared Wasserstein distance.

More precisely, let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a compact set and $c\in \Omega\times \Omega $ be continuous. Let $\nu\in P(\Omega)$ be a fixed probability measure,
and define the map $P(\Omega) \ni \mu\mapsto T(\mu,\nu)\in \mathbb {R}$ such that
$$
T(\mu,\nu)=\min_{\gamma \in \Pi(\mu,\nu)}\int_\Omega c(x,y)d \gamma,
$$
where $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is the set of probability measures with $\mu$ and $\nu$ as their first and second marginals, respectively.

As shown in Proposition 7.17 of [the book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-20828-2), $\mu\mapsto T(\mu,\nu)$ is convex and under suitable conditions on $\nu$ and $c$, for all $\mu,\mu'\in P(\Omega)$,
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{T(\mu+\epsilon (\mu'-\mu),\nu)}{\epsilon}=\int_\Omega \varphi_\mu (x) (\mu'-\mu)(dx),
$$
where $\varphi_\mu$ is the unique Kantorovich potential from $\mu$ to $\nu$.  This allows us to define the following Bregman divergence $D(\cdot|\cdot):P(\Omega)\times P(\Omega)\to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
D(\mu'|\mu)=T(\mu',\nu)-T(\mu,\nu)-\int_\Omega \varphi_\mu (x) (\mu'-\mu)(dx),
$$
where $\varphi_\mu (x)$ is the first variation of $  T(\cdot,\nu)$ at $\mu$.

Has the above Bregman divergence been studied in the literature? For instance, with specific choices of $c$, say $c(x,y)=|x-y|^2$, can we simplify the expression of $D(\mu'|\mu)$? Can we obtain its relation with commonly used metrics of probability measures?

Comment: I have come across a very similar construction in a few proofs, but I do not recall seeing it for the sake of defining a divergence. See Lemma 5.1 in  https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-50/issue-2/Multivariate-ranks-and-quantiles-using-optimal-transport--Consistency-rates/10.1214/21-AOS2136.full. 
It seems to be an upper bound on the linearised OT metric up to scaling (at first glance).

Comment: @GillesMordant Thanks for the reference. For clarity, in Lemma 5.2 of the reference, does $2g$ play the role of $\varphi_\mu$ in my question?

Comment: Yes, it should be an optimal dual potential.